# Flow of Android view

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

Can anyone explain me the flow from application to GPU to display..
I need it in terms of view in Android.

if I run an application which uses openGL, a view has to be created and when I press some home key or so the current application's will be invisible and start the home screen's view. Can I understand the flow?

what is the role of GPU here?